# How to completely show hide tabs on onclick event in HTML CSS Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I have small working project here.Please check the demo here:[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nLkZG/18/) I only have to make small changes in this by completely hiding the tabs. So when i run this project only 1 tab should be visible. And by clicking the image only tab2 should be visible. And while clicking the filter button on tab2 only tab1 should be visible.So basically i just want to visible only 1 tab . Any help ? Thanks.
Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dashboards</title>
       <style>
          body {
        padding: 5px;
      }
      margin : 5px;
    font: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #fff;
}

body {
    margin : 10px;
    font: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #fff;
}

.tab-links {
    border-bottom : 1px solid #ccc;
    margin : 0;
    padding-bottom : 19px;
    padding-left : 10px;
}

.tab-links ul, .tab-links li    {
    display : inline;
    list-style-type : none;
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
}


.tab-links a:link, .tab-links a:visited {
    background : #E8EBF0;
    border : 1px solid #ccc;
    color : #666;
    float : left;
    font-size : small;
    font-weight : normal;
    line-height : 14px;
    margin-right : 8px;
    padding : 2px 10px 2px 10px;
    text-decoration : none;
}

.tab-links a:link.active, #menu a:visited.active    {
    background : #fff;
    border-bottom : 1px solid #fff;
    color : #000;
}

.tab-links a:hover  {
    color : #f00;
}


body.tabs .tab-links li#nav-1 a, 
body.tabs .tab-links li#nav-2 a {
    background : #fff;
    border-bottom : 1px solid #fff;
    color : #000;
}

.tab-links #subnav-1,
.tab-links #subnav-2 {
    display : none;
    width: 90%;
}

body.tabs .tab-links ul#subnav-1, 
body.tabs .tab-links ul#subnav-2 {
    display : inline;
    left : 10px;
    position : absolute;
    top : 95px;
}

body.tabs .tab-links ul#subnav-1 a, 
body.tabs .tab-links ul#subnav-2 a {
    background : #fff;
    border : none;
    border-left : 1px solid #ccc;
    color : #999;
    font-size : smaller;
    font-weight : bold;
    line-height : 10px;
    margin-right : 4px;
    padding : 2px 10px 2px 10px;
    text-decoration : none;
}

 .tab-links ul a:hover {
    color : #f00 !important;
}

#contents {
    background : #fff;
    border : 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top : none;
    clear : both;
    margin : 0px;
    padding : 15px;
}

     #phones {
        font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        background: #fff;
        margin: 15px 25px 0 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        text-align: left;
        float: left;
      }

      #phones th {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #039;
        padding: 0px 1px;
        border-bottom: 12px solid #6678b1;
      }

      #phones td {
        border-bottom: 0px solid #ccc;
        color: #669;
        padding: 1px 1px;
      }

      #phones tbody tr:hover td {
        color: #009;
      }

      #filter {
        float:left;
      }

      fieldset{
        margin-top: 15px;
      }

      fieldset div{
        padding:0 0 5px 0;
      }

      .amount{
        width:50px;
      }

.active a{color:red !important; background-color:#fff !important}
.tab{display:none}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 

   <div class="tabs">
           <ul class="tab-links">
              <li id="nav-1" class='active'><a href="#tab1">Fahrzeuge</a></li>
              <li id="nav-2"><a href="#tab2">Edit Fahrzeuge</a></li>
           </ul>
   </div>


        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="tab1" class="tab" style='display:block'>
                <table id="phones">
                                <thead>
                                    <img id="filtered" src="edit.png" width="20" height="20" style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:10px; float: center;" >
                                <tr>

                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                </tbody>
                                    </table>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tab2" class="tab">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_mit_und_ohne_Bilder" checked />
                                        <label for="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_mit_und_ohne_Bilder">Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_mit_und_ohne_Bilder</label><br>

                        <input type="checkbox" id="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis" checked />
                                        <label for="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis">Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis</label>
                                        <button id="submitFilter">Filter</button> 
                     </div>
            </div>



        <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){    
                function makeTable(data){
        var tbl_body = "";
        $.each(data, function() {
          var tbl_row = "",
              currRecord = this;

          $.each(this, function(k , v) {
            if(k==='model'){
              v = "<a href='content.php?id=" + currRecord['id'] +"'>" + v + "</a>";
            } else if (k==='price'){
              v = "<span class='price'>" + v + "</span>";
            }
            tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
          })
          tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";
        })

        return tbl_body;
      }

      function getPhoneFilterOptions() {
     var opts = [];
     $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
         if (this.checked) {
             opts.push($(this).attr("id"));
         }
     });

     return opts;
 }

      function updatePhones(opts){
        if(!opts || !opts.length){
          opts = allBrands;
        }

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "submit.php",
          dataType : 'json',
          cache: false,
          data: {filterOpts: opts},
          success: function(records){
            $('#phones tbody').html(makeTable(records));

          }
        });
      }    

            $('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function (e) {
     var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');
    // alert('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue);
     // Show/Hide Tabs

     $('.tab-content ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

     // Change/remove current tab to active
     $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

     e.preventDefault();
 });



      $("#submitFilter").on("click", function () {
     var opts = getPhoneFilterOptions();
          updatePhones(opts);
          $('.tab-content #tab1').show().siblings().hide(); 
          e.preventDefault();
 });

 $("#filtered").on("click", function () {

          $('.tab-content #tab2').show().siblings().hide(); 
          e.preventDefault();
 });


      var allBrands = [];
      $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
        allBrands.push($(this)[0].id)
      })

      updatePhones();
});


    </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: your demo link is working fine. what else you required. Be more specific.

Comment: when you say 'only 1 tab should show', you mean only the content of the tab right..? not the tab itself (the btn on top)

Comment: ohh sorry i mean to say tab should not be visible. If the tab will not be visible  then the content will also not be visible right. SO this is not about content of the tab. Its about the complete tab. When we run this fiddle it will show 2 tabs Fahrzeuge and Edit Fahrzeuge. But i dont want that. I want only 1 tab should be visible i.e Fahrzeuge and the Edit Fahrzeuge tab will not be visible at all.And when i click the image on tab1 then the tab1 will gets completely invisible and tab2 will gets visible.

Comment: ??????? @user3659737
When we are running a fiddle we only see two tabs Tabs#1 and Tabs#2.
Fahrzeuge and edit Fahrzeuge are inside of Tabs#2. onload your fiddle will display the tabs not its content. onclick of any tab it will display content. Same is happening in your fiddle.

Comment: @Atal its all about tabs visibility.  Only 1 tab should be visible at the same time the other tab will be completely invisible.

Comment: @Eyal Only 1 button on top should show.

Comment: @Atal u r getting it wrong. Its not inside of Tabs#2. These are 2 completely different tabs Fahrzeuge and edit Fahrzeuge.Please check the code.

Comment: @Eyal exactly only 1 button on top should show

Comment: @user3659737 let's say onload only tab#1 is displayed.. how would you get tab#2 to display? there's nothing to click in tab#1.. what am i missing?

Comment: means when you click on the filter all other tabs heading and tabs content should hide and only tabs#1 will display

Comment: oh man! there is lot of confusion in this question.

Comment: @Eyal you can see image on #tab1. If you click on that image.The #tab1 button will not show the #tab2 button will show. And on #tab2 if you click on filter button then #tab2 button will not show and #tab1 button will show.

Comment: @AtalShrivastava i dont know ur confusion man. Its simple dont think about tab content. Think about button.

Comment: so on clicking filter only Tabs#1 button will show not others right?? @user3659737

Comment: @ Eyal http://jsfiddle.net/nLkZG/21/  Can you see the image now ?

Comment: @Atal now you got it .Please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nLkZG/21/

Comment: Actually img is there in `<div id="tab1" class="tab" style='display:block'><table id="phones"><thead>' in the question.
but is not there in the fiddle provided by @user3659737

Comment: check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/954wc/) @user3659737

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it:

```
.tab-links li { display:none;}
.tab-links li.active { display:inline;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aK7NB/

what I did is basically give the #nav li's 'display:none' and when they have class 'active' they are display:block.. then in the js just give the active class if you want to see and remove it if you want to hide... check the example

Comment: why Tabs#2 is hide on onload

Comment: that's what he asked : 'So when i run this project only 1 tab should be visible'

Comment: onclick of filter button tabs#2 has to hide what i understood.

Comment: @Eyal thank you its working :). Can we do small change in this. I want #tab1 will always show.And when you click on image in #tab1 then both #tab1 and #tab2 should show.And when you click on #tab2 filter button the #tab2 button should not be visible. So i am giving the priority to #tab1 button. And #tab2 button should only show on clicking image on #tab1. And gets hide once the filter button is clicked on it. So we are toggling #tab2. How can we do that ?

Comment: @Atal ur logic for #tab2 filter button is working :).But when you run the project both the tabs are showing initally.And we want only 1 tab to show i.e #tab1.Just a small change is required.

Comment: There's a few way to do that, I override the active class rules with an !important rule for tab#1 that will always be in display.. the other way to do it would be to never remove the active class from tab#1 in the javascript

Comment: @Eyal and  Atal thanks you very much its working perfectly.And i want to ask one question as you told me there are other ways to do that which one is the better and does it make impact on the performance ?

Comment: if you have only two tabs then it is ok if you have more tabs then each time you need to define a function for new tab, the way we goin. @user3659737

Comment: @user3659737 sure. The answer to your question really depends on the logic of your app... I'm pretty sure anything you can do with CSS rather then js is better for performance.. in your case I chose to override rather than leave the active class is because the tab is still displayed but it's not the active one.

Comment: ohh ok thanks @Atal one more question i have added reset button now in #tab2 and when i click reset button it should uncheck the checkbox. But its not working can you please check : http://jsfiddle.net/p2thC/3/

Comment: you haven't define the function for your reset button. Use jquery `:checked` for this. @user3659737

Comment: @AtalShrivastavata i will try to do that :)